# Remove write and modify files in php.ini

Tags: php

im trying to harden an old Joomla website that the owners wont pay to update, and it gets hacked all the time. Bear in mind they dont update it, so no user needs any file write permissions. Is it possible to modify the php.ini file so that no user has any file create or file modify permissions ?. As at the moment I spend hours removing or restoring the crap that is injected into the files, it would be far better if it could be made non writeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CHMOD it to 700, so only the owner will be able to create, modify and delete files.

Comment: Is there anyway they can bypass this, e.g by getting the server to mod the files ?, as I think they have been using mysql injection to mod the files, and have been creating junk files too.

Comment: Nobody can CHMOD files, only the owner. I don't think anyone can bypass this.

Comment: I take it this will leave the site so everyone else can view it ok ?

Comment: Everyone can visit the site, but only the site owner can create/modify/delete files

Answer (score 3):

CHMOD 700 from (possibly 777)-> only C,M,D rights for the owner

Comment: Is there anyway they can bypass this, e.g by getting the server to mod the files ?, as I think they have been using mysql injection to mod the files, and have been creating junk files too.

Comment: Only the owner and root can modify this

Comment: Does it leave the site viewable still ?