# Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

Ok, so I did as people said in the previous question [Remove write and modify files in php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595097/remove-write-and-modify-files-in-php-ini)
and chkmod'd the website files to 700 so only the owner could change them. Everyone said that I should be able to browse the website, but as soon as I do change them to 700 all I get is "403 forbidden Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.". Why is it blocking access when nearly every person that answered my previous question said it would work ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On folder 755, on files 444. When you edit files - return CHMOD on 644 and so editing